# how do I set the page title for a template wordpress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm fairly new to wp. I have found other people using this filter code at the top of the template to set the title for that page:

```
function assignPageTitle(){
  return "Custome Title";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
```

But I need to pass my `assignPageTitle` function 1 parameter from the query_vars `$wp_query->query_vars['claim_id']`, And my `getTitle` function builds the title based on the id of the content. Something like this i thought, but it does not work. `$wp_query->query_vars['claim_id']` is `null` when called inside this function:

```
function assignPageTitle(){
  return getTitle($wp_query->query_vars['claim_id']);
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
```

I see some people using parameters with these filters something like this:

```
function assignPageTitle($claim_id){
  return getTitle($claim_id);
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle',10,1);
```

But this is where I am getting extremely confused. WHERE is it that I can pass the claim_id variable to `assignPageTitle($claim_id)` function? Putting `assignPageTitle(312)` under that filter code does nothing, and `wp_title(234)` just echoes a title like string wherever I put it on the template page.

I also tried just editing the **functions.php** where the title is made:

```
<title><?php getTitle($wp_query->query_vars['claim_id']);?></title>
```

But `$wp_query->query_vars['claim_id']` is `null` when called in the functions.

I must be totally not understanding these filters, how can i get the title to be set to the output of `getTitle($wp_query->query_vars['claim_id'])` ?

Comment: Try adding a `global $wp_query;` as the first line within the `assignPageTitle()` function.

Comment: yep, it was a simple as that

Answer (score 1):

`$wp_query` is a global variable. To access a global variable in your code, you first need to globalize the variable with `global $variable;`. In your case, this means:

```
function assignPageTitle(){
    global $wp_query;
    return "Custome Title";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
```

There's more info about global WordPress variables [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables).